# jQuery AJAX submission with form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I've written some jQuery code which sends an AJAX request to my CMS to fire off different PHP actions depending on what action is sent in the request.

This is working fine, however the values of the form are not being sent with the AJAX post. I've tried various different methods such as new form and serializing the form data but nothing seems to be working for me.

I assumed that just including this into the call was going to be enough:

```
$formData = $('#checkout-cart').serialize();
data: $formData,
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
var formSubmit = {
    config: {
        guestUser: '.create-guest-user',
    },
    initialize: function () {
        var $this = this;
        $(this.config.guestUser).click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $this.createGuestUser();
            return false;
        });
    },
    // Create Guest User
    createGuestUser: function (elem) {
        $.post(window.location.href, {
            type: 'ajax',
            data: $formData,
            url: window.location.href,
            action: 'createGuestUser',
        }).done(function (response) {
            $('.create-guest-user').addClass('disabled');
        });
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    formSubmit.initialize();
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="checkout-form" action="cart/checkout/" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <fieldset id="account">
        <legend>Your Personal Details</legend>
        <div class="form-group" style="display: none;">
          <label class="control-label">Customer Group</label>
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="customer_group_id" value="1" checked="checked">
              Default
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-firstname">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="First Name" id="input-payment-firstname" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-lastname">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" placeholder="Last Name" id="input-payment-lastname" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-email">E-Mail</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-Mail" id="input-payment-email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-telephone">Telephone</label>
          <input type="text" name="telephone" value="" placeholder="Telephone" id="input-payment-telephone" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <fieldset id="address" class="required">
        <legend>Your Address</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-company">Company</label>
          <input type="text" name="company" value="" placeholder="Company" id="input-payment-company" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-address-1">Address 1</label>
          <input type="text" name="address_1" value="" placeholder="Address 1" id="input-payment-address-1" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-address-2">Address 2</label>
          <input type="text" name="address_2" value="" placeholder="Address 2" id="input-payment-address-2" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-city">City</label>
          <input type="text" name="city" value="" placeholder="City" id="input-payment-city" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-postcode">Post Code</label>
          <input type="text" name="postcode" value="" placeholder="Post Code" id="input-payment-postcode" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-country">Country</label>
          <select name="country_id" value="" id="input-payment-country" class="form-control">
            <option value="244">Aaland Islands</option><option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-zone">Region / State</label>
          <select name="zone_id" value="" id="input-payment-zone" class="form-control">
          </select>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <button id="button-guest" class="btn btn-primary create-guest-user get-shipping-methods" data-loading-text="Loading...">Continue</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: `type: 'ajax'` is not valid. It should be `type: "get"` or `type: "post"`.

Comment: And you only need that option when you use `$.ajax`. `$.post` automatically sets it to `post`.

Answer (score 2):

Please add url attribute to your `$.post`

```
  var formSubmit = {
      config: {
          guestUser: '.create-guest-user',
      },
      initialize: function () {
          var $this = this;
          $(this.config.guestUser).click(function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              $this.createGuestUser();
              return false;
          });
      },
      // Create Guest User
      createGuestUser: function (elem) {
          $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              data: $formData,
              url: 'url.php'
          }).done(function (response) {
              $('.create-guest-user').addClass('disabled');
          });
      }
  };

  $(document).ready(function () {
      formSubmit.initialize();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - no luck with that though I'm afraid.

Comment: Does the request goes to server?

Comment: The call goes to the server fine and fires off my PHP action scripts however I can't get hold of any $_POST values. I can also see when logging $formData to the browser console that it's being captured fine.

Comment: Can you also post your html form code in your question?

Comment: Thank you - I've updated the question with the HTML.

Comment: The first argument to `$.post` is the URL, you don't need to repeat it in the options argument.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `$.post` is just the post data, not an options argument. If you want to pass options, you need to use `$.ajax`, not `$.post`.

You also need to update `$formData` when making the AJAX call, otherwise you'll get the values of the form from when the page was initially loaded.

There's no `action` option to `$.ajax`. If you want to add additional POST parameters that aren't in form inputs, you need to add them to `$formData`.

```
createGuestUser: function (elem) {
    var $formData = 'action=createGuestUser&' + $('#checkout-cart').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: $formData,
        url: window.location.href,
    }).done(function (response) {
        $('.create-guest-user').addClass('disabled');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The action is being posted and captured by PHP in a switch statement.

Comment: You mean something like `$_POST['action']`?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to send an additional parameter in the POST data.

Comment: Thanks reply the reply. Not quite I meant that I was using it in this way.. passing the action into the switch case statement for different elements of the checkout page that gets submitted. Here's the trimmed version.

https://pastebin.com/z5aP6YHC

Comment: Your code there has `$action = $post['action'];` which is essentially what I said.

Comment: Sorry my mistake!

Comment: Ahh, now I see. These aren't actually `$.ajax` options, your PHP code uses `$post['type']`.

Comment: Thanks I tried your solution but my browser console is returning an error.
       'Uncaught TypeError: "action=createGuestUser&".$ is not a function'

Comment: Oops, got mixed up between PHP and JS, it should be `+`. But this code won't work at all with your framework, which wasn't explained anywhere in the question.